# Approach to an openGLES Bone animation solution

Tags: android, iphone, opengl-es, 3d, blender

Right this is more of a discussion where I am asking for a pointer in the right direction for further reading and more likely brain damage.

So in past work and also messing about in our company I have found multiple platform specific solutions to Exporting bone animation from Blender and importing to each platform. For instance the PowerVR SDK on the iPhone (which I have done in the past). Now of course this is reliant on PowerVR Chipsets and I am making a cross platform engine so doesn't fit my model.

So does anyone know a good place to look for either a tutorial on importing a mesh with bone animation from Blender (or even in general? ) to general OpenGLES (non platform specific)?

Or,

A some example code?  <<< I know there are no shortcuts and this is a mammoth job.

Essentially I am looking for a good starting point.

I am pretty sure that trying to do it in a cross platform manner will probably mean the engine takes a performance hit and also cause me headache's when I come to optimize later on, but more importantly is the cross platform ability so that is a hit I'm willing to take.

Comment: When you say PowerVR SDK on the iPhone, do you mean the matrix palette extension?

Comment: As in the tech by imagination Technologies who do the graphics chipsets have a full SDK and tutorials for performance enhanced rendering. Including bone animation and mesh format, how .PVR4 texture support works on iOS, among other things like anti aliased models. But it relies on the device having a PowerVR chipset, which on Android is about 5 devices. I am trying to work out a more over arching approach to hit more devices and not stick with platform dependency. A games company i used to work for had done this and it worked really nicely and that was about 6 years ago so i know its possible.

Comment: Okay, and just one more question — are you looking to target the ES 1 fixed pipeline or the ES 2 programmable pipeline? I appreciate a lot of the question is just how to get the data across rather than how to render it necessarily but it's relevant nonetheless.

Comment: Sorry i should of mentioned that, i am currently just doing fixed pipeline ES 1.1 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) for inspiration.  Its library is very cross-platform and mature and supports skeletal animation.

Be prepared to feel like you are writing a cheap imitation copy of it.

Comment: You know what that is a pretty good idea, do you know the license on it? i don't want to be breaching the hard work of many, but am happy to accept standing on the shoulders of giants :)

Comment: according to http://www.ogre3d.org/licensing/licensing-faq it's an MIT license. I believe if you take an extract you are required to also use the MIT license.  But you are perfectly allowed to use its ideas in your own code.

Comment: Thankyou Michael i will take a look at this in toe coming week and report back.